# Need T-SQL Query for Groups and Islands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

```
create table #sample (rowguid int identity ,id_frm int ,id_to int)

insert into #sample values( 1,5)
insert into #sample values( 7,13)
insert into #sample values( 17,20)
```

In the above table I have values starting Id and Ending Id. I need to prepare a table which has all the numbers falls between starting Id and Ending Id

i have tried it with looping but response is very slow in real world.

any body help me with query ???

This is what I have tried so far...

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)  = '  
select top '+cast((select  max(id_to) from #sample) as varchar(100))+' identity(int,1,1) as guidid into  tally from sysobjects,syscolumns '

exec (@sql)


alter table Tally add slab varchar(10)

create clustered index  idx on Tally(guidid)
create  clustered index  idx on #sample(id_frm asc,id_to desc)

update Tally set slab = rowguid 
from #sample join Tally on guidid between id_frm and id_to 

delete from Tally where slab is null

select * from Tally
```

This query works fine with small numbers

But My real time table have 13 digit nos. It through Arithmetic overflow error

Comment: Sure.. I have tried with the looping but it wont help me ... lagging in performance.

Comment: Please can you give an example of your expected table?

Comment: Please update your question with the query you've tried.

Comment: you do not specify clearly how your expected output should look like `a table which has all the numbers falls between starting Id and Ending Id` isnt very precise, a table with one column? With ALL numbers between id_frm and id_to from ALL the rows inside `sample`? or one table per row in sample with one column holding a number? please try to be as specific as you can to make helping you possible and also help us in helping you by showing what you already tried `i have tried it with looping but response is very slow in real world.` => show that try to us, it will clear things up

Comment: What do islands have to do with anything?

Comment: @Hituptony because it falls into a category of problems described as ["gaps and islands"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+gaps+and+islands)

Comment: Check this articles for varios tehnique of generating sequence plus performance testing of each one - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: As a general rule, it's always good to have a numbers\tally table in the database. It makes solving issues like this easier, plus it also offers solutions to other problems which can improve performance. IMHO they should come as standard with any SQL DB installation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the range `id_frm` and `id_to` is relatively small integers, e.g. < 1M, one technique to approach this problem is to create a table with all values in the range and join to it:

```
WITH lotsOfNumbers AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o1.object_id) AS id
   FROM sys.objects o1 CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2 
)
INSERT INTO #targetTable
SELECT l.ID
   FROM lotsOfNumbers l
   INNER JOIN #sample
   ON l.ID BETWEEN #sample.id_frm AND #sample.id_to;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17137)

A permanent table with the necessary range of ID's and a clustered index on the ID would improve performance, obviously.

Add in a `DISTINCT` if your ranges overlap, and you don't want duplicates in the result.

Comment: @vignesh For your 13 digit range you'll need to model the values as BIGINTs. With some luck you will only need a small dynamic range (i.e. not everything from zero to 10^13 at the same time), and you can gradually adjust the numbers table to span the probable range needed?

Answer (score -2):

If you are able to get a full range of acceptable values into another table, you can use it without looping. The meathod below gets the minimum (1) and maximum (20), and the temporary table named #range will return everything in between.

```
drop table #sample
drop table #range 

create table #sample (id_frm int ,id_to int)

insert into #sample values( 1,5)
insert into #sample values( 7,13)
insert into #sample values( 17,20) 



create table #range (id  int)



insert into #range select 1
go

insert into #range   select top 1 max(id)+ 1   from #range  
go 100

declare @min int
declare @max int

set @min= (select min(id_frm ) from #sample )
set @max =  (select   max(id_to) from #sample )
select * from #range where id between @min and @max
```

Comment: code only answers are not encouraged on stackoverflow! this place is about `answering questions` not just `throwing some code around` without explanations

Comment: @DrCopyPaste what? Not encouraged by who? If code is the answer then fine. Code with explanation is better of course, but in this case it is pretty clear.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste this argument can be partially valid in case of obvious homework questions (because ready code ruins the meaning of studying), but for general questions it is nonsense.

Comment: @Andrey it is just that imho code without explanation makes such questions for future readers much less time efficient, because they cannot simply read your explanation and apply it to their code, they have to read both the asker's and your code and compare to understand, as to where this is encouraged, `Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.` http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @DrCopyPaste first you patronize dirtyw0lf and now you patronize me. Maybe you should chill out a little bit? Nobody is arguing that code + explanation is better but this is about helping people for free and if answer is good but not perfect then it deserves upvote, later OP will pick the best answer and that is how things work here. If you think that code is not clear enough you *can* politely ask to comment the code.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I completely agree with your comments. And I wonder why this answer has 2 upvotes as it is useless, it does not solve the gaps and islands problem of the OP.

Comment: @Andrey Maybe you should read your last comment and then **your** comments and realize who really needs to "chill out a little"